# How to stream system sounds to Android device in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio

My desktop speaker is dead and I want to listen to sounds using my phone over Bluetooth or shared Wi-Fi. How could it be done? There are similar questions but too old and mostly not working.

Comment: Give this a try https://georgielabs.net/

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi It could only record my mic for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AudioRelay](https://audiorelay.net/) works well for me with low latency